# TTOpenURL() - Secure Password protected link open ? It's don't work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I use the TTCatalog for my Project. I call a Website with this Code:

```
TTOpenURL(@"http://www.MySecureWebsite.me");
```

But Websites with password protected Link's don't work. Other Links works (e.g. www.google.com) works.

It's not a Website with https Protocol, only a http with authorization.

I hope you can help me!

Thanks a lot - best regards from Germany

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to call NSURLCredentialStorage & friends before calling TTOpenURL? You can set different persistence modes (none, session, permanent = keychain), etc. etc.

```
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc] initWithHost:@"www.MySecureWebsite.me" port:80 protocol:@"http" realm:@"server's realm" authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPBasic];

[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:credential forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

[protectionSpace release];
```

Comment: Hmm and when i will popup an Alert for Username & Password ? Like Safari ? Whats This: realm:@"server's realm" ?

Comment: And how i make this with the TTTableTextItem? There i call the Website so: `[TTTableTextItem itemWithText:@"Monday" URL:@"http://www.MySecureWebsite.me"
           accessoryURL:nil],`